# Pass objects from client side and access from server side - Knockoutjs

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I'm working with Knockout basics. 
I'm passing data from client side to server side by calling WebForm3.aspx/saveData. For making simple I pass data by data (txtName, txtEmail, txtAge).

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebForm3.aspx/saveData",
                data: "{name:'" + txtName + "',email:'" + txtEmail + "',age:'" + txtAge + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "jsondata",
                async: "true",
                success: function (response) {
                    $(".errMsg ul").remove();
                    var myObject = eval('(' + response.d + ')');
                    if (myObject > 0) {
                        bindData();
                        $(".errMsg").append("<ul><li>Data saved successfully</li></ul>");

                    }
                    else {
                        $(".errMsg").append("<ul><li>Opppps something went wrong.</li></ul>");
                    }
                    $(".errMsg").show("slow");
                    clear();
                },
```

So I can access those data in my server side code as below.

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static int saveData(string name, string email, string age)
        {

    }
```

Now time arrives to refactor my code and don't want to pass data by data. As an alternative I want to pass an object it contains all the properties.
Can someone suggest how to pass objects and access it from server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jquery serialize() method to get the data object of some form like

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="text" name="age" />
</form>
```

Get form data by

`var postData = $("#myForm").serialize();`

call ajax using below option

```
 data:postData
```

Comment: This is fine. Then how to use this in server side code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any knockout code here but it seems like you're using jquery's ajax method which should accept plain javascript objects for the 'data' field so you don't have to write a messy long concatenated string ("data by data")

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings